# Skip a specific warning/note with Proguard?

Tags: java, warnings, obfuscation, proguard

In my Java program I download and load SWT library dynamically. So I use this snippet to check whether downloaded jar is valid or not.

```
try {
   Class.forName("org.eclipse.swt.SWT");
   //valid swt.jar
} catch (Exception e) {
    //wrong swt.jar
}
```

But when I use ProGuard to obfuscate my jar the line above produces following note/warning

```
 [proguard] Note: org.MyClass: can't find dynamically referenced class org.eclipse.swt.SWT
 [proguard] Note: there were 1 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
```

Of course I can disable any note for the **whole** class

```
-dontnote org.MyClass
```

but I want to disable only this specific note and see others for the same class.

Is it possible? I have inspected [Usage Manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html) but could not find out how to achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also specify the referenced class:

```
-dontnote org.eclipse.swt.SWT
```

That doesn't disable any notes about your own code.

Comment: please, see new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098225/what-are-features-of-using-proguard-in-project-with-protocol-buffers