# What are features of using Proguard in project with Protocol Buffers?

Tags: java, obfuscation, protocol-buffers, proguard

I have a project in where Google Protocol Buffers are used. Once I try to obfuscate it with ProGuard it seems that protobuf causes problem.

All my own classes I package into `mybuildedclasses.jar`. Google code is packaged into `protbuf.jar`

```
mybuildedclasses.jar
protobuf.jar
other external jars
```

After that I am trying to obfuscate `mybuildedclasses.jar`. Config file is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7511926/1360074). Eventually all jars are packaged inside another fat jar.

I run the program and once message is tried to be sent this kind of Exceptions are printed.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Generated message class "org.mypackage.messages.Control$MessageControlHandCard$Builder" missing method "getCardId".
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.getMethodOrDie(GeneratedMessage.
java:1366)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.access$1(GeneratedMessage.java:1
361)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$FieldAccessorTable$SingularField
Accessor.<init>(GeneratedMessage.java:1502)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$FieldAccessorTable.<init>(Genera
tedMessage.java:1441)
        at org.mypackage.Control$1.assignDescriptors(SourceFile:32
20)
        at com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.internalBuildGenerated
FileFrom(Descriptors.java:300)
        at org.evogame.common.messages.Control.<clinit>(SourceFile:3278)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.evogame.common.messages.Control$
MessageControlHandCard$Builder.getCardId()
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1622)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.getMethodOrDie(GeneratedMessage.
java:1364)
```

And

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.mypackage.messages.Control$MessageControlGameRequest.interna
lGetFieldAccessorTable(SourceFile:527)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.getAllFieldsMutable(GeneratedMes
sage.java:105)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.getAllFields(GeneratedMessage.ja
va:153)
        at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.print(TextFormat.java:229)
        at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Printer.access$2(TextFormat.java:226)
        at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat.print(TextFormat.java:69)
        at com.google.protobuf.TextFormat.printToString(TextFormat.java:116)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessage.toString(AbstractMessage.java:87)
```

If I don't obfuscate then everything works perfectly. **So how should particularly configure `-keep` option for Google Protocol Buffers related code?**

I have tried for generated message files, but it give same exceptions.

```
-keep public class org.mypackage.messages.* {
 }
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? If yes please can you share your findings? Am stuck at the same issue for long time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like this may just be a matter of the package being misaligned. Look at the error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Generated message class 
     "org.mypackage.Control$MessageControlHandCard$Builder" 
      missing method "getCardId".
 ...
```

So that's `org.mypackage.Control`.

Now look at your Proguard configuration:

```
-keep public class org.mypackage.messages.* {
}
```

That's using `org.mypackage.messages`, which wouldn't include `org.mypackage.Control`.

Now presumably those aren't your *real* package names - but if they're representative, it sounds like you need to change your `.proto` file to emit classes in the package `org.mypackage.messages` instead of `org.mypackage`. (You could change your Proguard configuration instead, but it sounds like that would pick up too much.)

Alternatively, you might be able to just use the inheritance tree. I'm not a Proguard user myself, but judging by the [examples](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/examples.html), you might want:

```
-keep public class * extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage
```

I'd expect that to work on all your protocol buffer classes regardless of package. You *may* find that there are other fields/methods which protobuf expects in the "top level" class though.

EDIT: Looking at the documentation further, it may be that you need:

```
-keep public class * extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage { *; }
```

or

```
-keep public class * extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite { *; }
```

to preserve all members as well. There are other "keep" options which are looking at instead of `-keep`, such as `-keepnames`.

Comment: Thanks for the first answer. `this may just be a matter of the package being misaligned` - I think it was just a typo when manually renaming my real package name to post here. I have edited the question.

Comment: `-keep public class * extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage` I would need to try that. Though I don't fully understand whether it would keep only names of classes or also names of every method and field inside it.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov: You think, or you've verified? This is where it would be worth putting the *exact* error message and the *exact* Proguard configuration line, without changing them... Note that the second exception in your question has the same problem...

Comment: Now I have huge refactoring ongoing, so the project is not compileable, so I cannot check right now. The second error is part of the same stack trace..

Comment: I think for generated messages for protobuffers I need to keep everything: names of the classes, fields and methods. For name the command I have used and suggested by you keep only classes names. So next time I can build the project I would try to modify that command.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov: See my edit for another couple of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer specifying the field name instead of keeping whole class members, which producing much smaller output.

```
-keepclassmembers your.class.name {
  int sampleIntField;
  String sampleStringField;
}
```